# SORT empties my file?

Tags: linux, command-line, sorting

I'm attempting to `sort` a csv on my machine, but I seem to be erasing the contents each time I use the `sort` command. I've basically created a copy of my csv lacking the first row:

```
sed '1d' original.csv > newcopy.csv
```

To confirm that my new copy exists lacking the first row I can check with `head`:

```
head 1 newcopy.csv
```

Sure enough, it finds my file and shows me the original second now (now first row). My csv consists of numerous values seperated by commas:

```
Jonathan Sampson,,,,foo@bar.com,,,GA,United States,,
Jane Doe,Mrs,,,bar@foo.com,,,FL,United States,32501,
```

As indicated above, some fields are empty. I want to sort based upon the email address field, which is either 4, or 5 - depending on whether the `sort` command uses a zero-based index. So I'm trying the following:

```
sort -t, +4 -5 newcopy.csv > newcopy.csv
```

So I'm using `-t,` to indicate that my fields are terminated by the comma, rather than a space. I'm not sure if `+4 -5` actually sorts on the email field or not - I could use some help here. And then `newcopy.csv > newcopy.csv` to overwrite the original file with new sort results.

After I do this, if I try to read in the first line:

```
head 1 newcopy.csv
```

I get the following error:

> head: cannot open `1' for reading: No such file or directory ==> newcopy.csv <==

Sure enough, if I check my directory the file is now empty, and 0 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redirection truncates the output file before it's read on the input side. You'll need to use a temp file.

**Edit:**

Here's an example:

```
sort -t, -k 5,5 newcopy.csv > tmp.csv && mv tmp.csv newcopy.csv
```

Sort fields are one-based. This command says to sort based on field five only, output to a temp file and only move the temp file back to the original name if the sort exited with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that `sort` has `-o` parameter which write results to the file, instead of standard output, so you should do:

```
sort -t, +4 -5 -o newcopy.csv newcopy.csv
```

since when using redirection operator (such as `>` or `>>`) shell creates/truncates file before the command is even invoked.